# Getting wrong results when trying to get the sum and averages for each month

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have an `orders` table. And I need to get the total `order_sum` for each month and also the daily average for each month.

For example, we can see that for `Jan 1` the total sum is `57.86` and for `Jan 2` the total sum is `44.61`. Then the daily average for the month of `January` would be `51.24`. But my query is getting me wrong results for `daily_average` *(It's showing 28.93)*.

Here is my `orders` table

```
+----+-----------+---------------------+-------------------------------+
| id | order_sum | created_at          |                               |
+----+-----------+---------------------+-------------------------------+
| 1  | 47.36     | 2020-01-01 08:02:17 |                               |
| 2  | 10.50     | 2020-01-01 11:19:00 | <-- total for Jan 1 is 57.86  |
|    |           |                     |                               |
| 3  | 5.04      | 2020-01-02 09:21:43 |                               |
| 4  | 39.57     | 2020-01-02 12:59:28 | <-- total for Jan 2 is 44.61  |
|    |           |                     |                               |
| 5  | 63.01     | 2020-02-01 17:04:50 |                               |
| 6  | 7.00      | 2020-02-01 19:36:02 | <-- total for Feb 1 is 70.01  |
|    |           |                     |                               |
| 7  | 3.12      | 2020-02-02 07:20:11 |                               |
| 8  | 119.98    | 2020-02-02 23:51:51 | <-- total for Feb 2 is 123.10 |
+----+-----------+---------------------+-------------------------------+
```

Here is my query (wrong)

```
select
  MONTH(created_at) as month,
  sum(order_sum) as order_sum,
  second_table.daily_average as daily_average
from
  orders
inner join (
  select
    month(created_at) as month,
    avg(order_sum) as daily_average
  from
    orders
  group by date(created_at)
) as second_table on MONTH(created_at) = second_table.month
group by
  MONTH(created_at);
```

This is the desired result I am trying to get

```
+-------+-----------+---------------+
| month | order_sum | daily_average |
+-------+-----------+---------------+
| 1     | 102.47    | 51.24         |
| 2     | 193.11    | 96.56         |
+-------+-----------+---------------+
```

Here is a sample schema...

```
CREATE TABLE orders(
   id         INTEGER  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
   order_sum  NUMERIC(11,2) NOT NULL,
   created_at VARCHAR(21) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO orders(id, order_sum, created_at) VALUES 
(1, 47.36, '2020-01-01 08:02:17'),
(2, 10.50, '2020-01-01 11:19:00'),
(3, 5.04, '2020-01-02 09:21:43'),
(4, 39.57, '2020-01-02 12:59:28'),

(5, 63.01, '2020-02-01 17:04:50'),
(6, 7.00, '2020-02-01 19:36:02'),
(7, 3.12, '2020-02-02 07:20:11'),
(8, 119.98, '2020-02-02 23:51:51');
```

... and fiddle of same:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/36ae43/7

Comment: What is the daily average if there are no sales on that day?

Comment: @GordonLinoff then the total for the day would be 0. And the daily average for the month would be ... (10 + 5 ... + 0) / count

Comment: You are grouping at different grains.  In your inner query you are grouping by day, and in your outer query you are grouping by month.  As @GordonLinoff says below, you should always include year if you are grouping by month.

Answer (score 3):

You should always include `year()` when working with months, unless you intend to leave it out.

I think you want:

```
select year(created_at) as year, month(created_at) as month,
       sum(order_sum) as order_sum,
       sum(order_sum) / count(distinct date(created_at)) as daily_average
from orders o
group by year(created_at), month(created_at);
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon, looks like this is exactly what I needed!